# Angular 2 how to define base URL forHttp requests

Tags: php, laravel, angular, api

I have declared the `http` url manually in my application.It is ok for local environment but when its get ready to deployment on server, it needs to be changed according to the server host. So I need a solution for how to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways which i know

1. Create one env.js file and write below code

   ```
     (function (window) {

      window.__env = window.__env || {};

     // API url
     window.__env.baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

     // Base url
      window.__env.middleware = '/api/v1';

     // Whether or not to enable debug mode
     // Setting this to false will disable console output
     window.__env.enableDebug = true;
   }(this));
   ```
2. You use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which i use to prefer. It helps us in managing the headers and separates our API related code. Example:

   ```
   var axios = require('axios');
   var axiosApi = axios.create({

       baseURL: config.host,

       headers: {

      // "authorization": "Basic dXNlckBjbG9uZWN0LmNvbTpQYXNzQDEyMw==",
         "content-type": "application/json"
       },
     // withCredentials: true,
         auth: {
           username: config.user,
           password: config.password
         }
      })
   ```

Whereas config.host, config.user are the variables declared in config.js based upon your environment type.